# Boostrap javascript form validation

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I doing a bootstrap and javascript form validation. What I am checking is if the form was filled out or not. One the form I left the two radio buttons uncheck, when I submit the form the warning message comes up and says that you must select an option. When I select an option and click on submit it doesn't submit he form. I've implemented the code below and so far the code is showing the warning message that the form wasn't completed.

```js
/****** Checks to see if the form is filled out
****************************************************** */
function validateForm() {
  var radios = document.getElementsByClassName(".form-check-input");
  var formValid = false;

  var i = 0;
  while (!formValid && i < radios.length) {
      if (radios[i].checked){
        formValid = true;
      i++;    
      }     
  }
if (!formValid){ $("#modalButton").click(function(){
    $("#buttonAlert").addClass('show') //Shows Bootstrap alert
  });
return formValid;
  }
  else{
    return true;
  }

}
```

what am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Ok cool. now it does the validation but it does not submit the form. I tried removing the return true and it does nothing like its in a null state. I tried removing the return formvalid, it submits the form but doesn't do the validation. I put the form and the full js validation in the link jsfiddle.net/dctech/sdw8jmue

Answer (score 0):

The formValid rule must be within the click event:

```
function validateForm() {
  var radios = document.getElementsByClassName(".form-check-input");
  var formValid = false;

  var i = 0;
  while (!formValid && i < radios.length) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
      formValid = true;
      i++;
    }
  }

  if (!formValid) {
    $("#buttonAlert").addClass('show')
    return formValid;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: ok. thanks, I've tried what you suggested and now it just submits the form without validating it

Comment: Ok, I edited the code, I think that way it will work.

Comment: Ok cool. now it does the validation but it does not submit the form. I tried removing the return true and it does nothing like its in a null state. I tried removing the return formvalid, it submits the form but doesn't do the validation. I put the form and the full js validation in the link https://jsfiddle.net/dctech/sdw8jmue/